# django rest framework many to many serialize and apiview

Tags: django-rest-framework

I am creating APIView for book list and add, delete.
Is this serialization the right way?
I want to show a list of books, but I do not know what to put in '?'.

member/models.py

```
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username = models.EmailField(unique=True, max_length=256)
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    mybook = models.ManyToManyField(Book)
```

book/models.py

```
from django.db import models


class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

book/seralizers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers

from book.models import Book


class MyBookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    mybook = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = (
            'title',
            'author',
    )
```

apiview.py

```
class MyBook(APIView):

    def get(self, request):
        mybook = Book.objects.filter(myuser=?)
        serializer = MyBookSerializer(mybook)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

    def post(self, request):
        pass

    def delete(self, request):
        pass
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want create a CRUD for model, depends on a `request.user` you can simply use `ModelViewSet`:

```
from rest_framework import viewsets

class MyBookViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = MyBookSerializer

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        return Book.objects.filter(myuser=self.request.user)
```

That's all for view. You only need to specify router for a viewset.
urls.py:

```
from rest_framework import routers

router = routers.DefaultRouter()

router.register('books', MyBookViewSet)
urlpatterns = []
urlpatterns += router.urls
```

Include this usl file in a root urls and you are done.
You also need to specify `related_name` for m2m field if you want to use `myuser` name:
 `mybook = models.ManyToManyField(Book, related_name='myuser')`
And you don't need this field in a serializer:
`mybook = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)`
[viewsets docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/)
[routers docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/)